# Isolated gate driver for the Class D amplifer

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, gate-driving, class-d

I am trying to simulate the gate driver part for driving the MOSFETs in the class D amplifier with [4N25 optocoupler](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf), not too sure if the connection between 4N25 and MOSFETs is correct.[image]

Comment: Why are V3 and V4 pulse generators?

Comment: Note that this is a very simple design. It is OK for use in a simulator and to "play around" with. However there is no provision to prevent the situation that M1 and M2 are conducting at the same time, that would **short** the power supply (for a short time but still enough for too much current to flow)!

Comment: Those had better be fast optoisolators ... most optos are way too slow for decent PWM performance, which si why it usually isn't done that way. Also, V3 cannot drive both gates : fi it can drive M2 it's at entirely the wrong voltage to drive M1. And if it can drive M1 it'll probably blow the gate off M2.

Comment: This is not a practical circuit for audio PWM. The 4N25s are glacially slow with 10K loads even without the (massive) MOSFET gate charge. Also you've set what should be power supplies as pulses for some reason, and M1 is a source follower so it can't output more than a few volts (and will get really hot). I suggest you find a circuit that is known to work and try to understand it.

Comment: If you want to isolate your FET drivers, I suggest using an actual isolated FET driver.  Much easier to use and more capable than optos for this application.